# iOS crashes and says lost connection when logging in facebook but works fine on Android from flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, facebook, crash

I don't know what seems to be the problem. It works fine on android but the app crashes on iOS after signing in to Facebook. It says lost connection to device and failed to send request. Where can I see the request? Please help me.
Here's the sample error output from flutter.

```
Lost connection to device.
Failed to send request: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"152","method":"getVM","params":{}}
```

Here's my Info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
      <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
      <array>
        <string>fb***************</string>
      </array>
      </dict>
    </array>
    <key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>***************</string>
    <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
    <string>MobileConnection</string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>pump_it</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
    <!-- Google Sign-in Section -->
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.************-*******************</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <!-- End of the Google Sign-in Section -->

</dict>
</plist>
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when using google and fb sign in together there are some conflicts in the system so we need to manually modify the list,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>

    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>

    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>

    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>

    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>Sunrise Checkin</string>

    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>

    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>

    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>

    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.googleusercontent.apps******************</string>
                <string>fb***********</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>************</string>
    <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
    <string>*********</string>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fbapi20130214</string>
        <string>fbapi20130410</string>
        <string>fbapi20130702</string>
        <string>fbapi20131010</string>
        <string>fbapi20131219</string>
        <string>fbapi20140410</string>
        <string>fbapi20140116</string>
        <string>fbapi20150313</string>
        <string>fbapi20150629</string>
        <string>fbapi20160328</string>
        <string>fbauth</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
    </array>

    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>

    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>

    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>

    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>

    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>

    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>

    <key>io.flutter.embedded_views_preview</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

modify your plist as so, and I hope it works for you as it did for me

Comment: @nit21 glad to be of help